# SSH Server Not Autostarting on Apple TV

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh, appletv

I have an Apple TV onto which I installed Ubuntu Karmic. It works great save a small problem with SSH.

The `openssh-server` package is installed and configured and can be started with `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start` fine. When the machine is rebooted, however, it never starts itself up as it should.

`rcconf` reports that SSH is enabled for autostart on boot. Grepping `/var/log/syslog`, `/var/log/messages`, and `/var/log/dmesg` for 'ssh' yields no results. I removed and readded ssh with the following: `sudo update-rc.d ssh start 40 2 3 4 5 . stop 19 0 1 6 .`.

Does anyone know what could be causing this to not start up properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure as to the reason for your problem, but you could put the start command into /etc/rc.local and see if that works.  It will be run as root, so don't put in the sudo.

/etc/rc.local

```
...
/etc/init.d/ssh start
exit 0
```

Comment: My `rc.local` isn't even being run. Ugh. Symlinks are present in the `rc#.d` folders and I tried redoing them with `update-rc.d` but they still don't fire.

Comment: I have larger underlying problems it seems. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wish I could be more help, but it appears this problem goes a bit deeper, beyond my knowledge.  Maybe the system is not switching run levels appropriately?

Comment: All of the guides for the Apple TV use Hardy except for one that used Karmic which I chose to follow. I did a complete fresh install with the 10.10 beta out of frustration which is working immensely better thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

If the other system startup options aren't working for you, try going to:

System  -->  Preferences --> Startup Applications

and adding the command there by using the "Add" button.